bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones
My problem is that when linking the rig to the model, it gives an error: bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones.
I don’t know what to do with this; I’ve already deleted duplicate vertices.
If this helps somehow, the model is imported from DAZ 3d in .obj format, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this

could you please share your file?

@moonboots, sure
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXukhvxAchbYZ5Dz0SiCYCXFBV1oTbBt/view?usp=drive_link

Have a look through the 'Related' questions in the column to the right of your question and see if any of the answers there help.

@Дарк that link is requesting access so we can't download the file.

@JohnEason I'm so sorry... How can I upload a file here? This is my first time here and I don’t know yet, haha..

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload

@moonboots
https://workupload.com/file/Kc7JMwqcQFd
Done, thanks!

could you please share the blend file instead (with the armature)?

@moonboots
Yes, Although this was not necessary, since when trying to create even a homemade simple skeleton, the same error appears.
The only thing that happens is that the rig gets attached to the clothes, although I didn’t even select them or add parent with automatic weights
https://workupload.com/file/5QC2fBPBn7K

@Mr-A If you have a different question please open a new post. Don't edit your posts into a completely different question, otherwise the comments, answers and linked questions people post will no longer apply, and it will make no sense for someone trying to read it.

The mesh you're trying to auto-weight is too dense and has extra geometry like hair and teeth.
Typically, in this situation, a simplified version of the mesh is weighted, and the weights are transferred to the high-poly version and to the extra geometry (and optionally refined a bit).
The solution I propose involves:

Extracting just the body mesh which means the extra meshes won't be considered in the first pass auto-weighting step.



Decimating the extracted body mesh. This will make it light enough for auto-weighting to succeed.



Auto-weighting the resulting mesh.



Manually refining the weights to get better deformations.

Transferring the weights to the original mesh and extra meshes.



I doubt that it will be possible to animate using the high-poly mesh in Blender. Maybe the decimated mesh will be useful for this too.

Sounds... Quite complicated, how can this be fixed?
Need to do a retopology?

The mesh is just too dense to auto-weight. You can probably manually paint the weights, but it's going to be too heavy to work with. As I suggested in my answer, I think the best approach is to extract the body geometry and decimate it. I don't think retopology is necessary, since the geometry is just sub-divided. The subdivision can be undone with the decimate modifier as mentioned in my answer. Once you auto-weight the unsubdivided version, you can transfer the weights to the original and to the other geometries.

It sounds quite complicated, can you somehow explain in more detail about extracting geometry and deleting it? I don't understand it well enough yet... :)

@Дарк I expanded my explanation and added GIFs to help illustrate the steps. I hope this helps. I still didn't show everything... Rigging is quite technical and time-consuming.

Thanks! I will try and figure it out further, you best!

Аnd I didn’t plan to animate this model, it’s too complicated for that, just making image renderings, that’s my thing :)

You're welcome!
