How to Properly Merge a Model Composed of Multiple Objects into a Single Object
I am new to blender. I downloaded a model from GitHub and want to rig a humanoid skeleton to use Mixamo animations.

To achieve this, I first need to combine the objects into a single piece. When I tried using Ctrl + J, I encountered the error: 'Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find a solution for one or more bones.' I searched online and attempted the 'merge by distance' method, which reduced over 20,000 vertices but ended up ruining the model.
My question is: how can I properly merge these objects into one while avoiding such issues, so I can successfully rig the bones?
Thanks!

I mean that after using Ctrl + J to merge the model and then parenting the rig to the merged model, I encounter the error: 'Bone Heat Weighting"

I don't know what error that is, but are you planning to move it like a robot? That is, no deformation of the solid parts? If so, then you want to parent the objects to the bone that is going to control them, not use automatic weights. Merging them all into 1 object is not necessary for this
Go into pose mode in the armature and select one of the objects in the hierarchy on the right, then select the bone that would control it and press ctrl+p -> Bone

@Demo There are many many entries here if you type "bone heat weighting" into the search. Have you at least tried to find out if there is something that helps? Like this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/ or this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/326493/
